# Final variable in java

Tags: java, variables, static, initialization, final

```
 class Test {
     public static final int x;
     public static void main (String[] args) {
         Test.x = 42;
     }
 }
```

I have declared a static final variable, and when i compiled it the following error shown up.

```
 error: cannot assign a value to final variable x
 Test.x = 42;
```

i think i have reached to the solution but i want to check if i am right or not?

I know that a static variable if not initialized is provided a default value. As it is a static final int variable it will be assigned a value of 0. later on, i tried to change the value to 42 which is not possible because the variable is final and cannot be changed from 0.

am i right or is there some other answer to it?

Comment: final variables can not changed after they are initialized.

Comment: The error exactly tells you what is wrong.

Comment: This is a question that you can simply get the answer to through reading about the `final` keyword on the java site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `final` member can only be assigned to directly in its initialization or in a constructor.  Since `main()` is neither of those things, it can't assign a value to the `final` member.  It's already "final" by the time that code executes.

Since this `final` member is `static`, unless you assign the value in the declaration you'd have to assign its value in a static initializer.  For example:

```
class Test {
    public static final int x;

    static {
        x = 42;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

final variables can only be initialized once in java.

non-static final variables can be initialized once in constructor,

and static final variables can be initialized once in static block,

apart from initializing them at declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test 
{
   public static final int x = 42;
   //...
}
```

will do it.

Answer (score -1):

You are almost correct. Only comment would be, all instance variables are initialized with default value, be it static or non-static. When you mark it `final`, compiler makes sure it is initialized only once.